# Programatically adding methods from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, syntax, nested-loops

Say I have an object created using `require('require-all')`

```
tasks = {
    getProfile: [constructor function]
    initAll: [constructor function]
    login: [constructor function]
};
```

How can I add the appropriate methods to the API programmatically without using `eval`?

```
API.prototype.getProfile = function(){
    this.runTask(new tasks.getProfile());
};

API.prototype.initAll = function(){
    this.runTask(new tasks.initAll());
};

API.prototype.login = function(){
    this.runTask(new tasks.login());
}
```

the tasks need to be able to run recursively, calling on `runTask` on themselves again (so I really need something programmatically equivalent)

Comment: Use `var func = new Function(argNames,functionBody);` look it up at MDN

Comment: That's still kind of like using `eval` but okay, I accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just asking how to build the `API.prototype` programmatically when given a `tasks` object, you can do something like this:

```
let tasks = {
    getProfile: [constructor function]
    initAll: [constructor function]
    login: [constructor function]
};

// populate API.prototype based on items in tasks
Object.keys(tasks).forEach(prop => {
    API.prototype[prop] = function() {
        this.runTasks(new (tasks[prop])());
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! I did something similar:
    for(var task in tasks){API.prototype[task]=function(){
  this.runTasks(new tasks[task]);
 };
    }`   

But it gave me the wrong context and just gave me the last item it processed.

Comment: @TeeraMusic - In a modern JS engine, yours would have worked using `let` instead of `var` with `for (let task in tasks) {....}` because `let` in a `for` loop creates a new variable for each iteration of the loop so it would have been correct.  But, since I used `.forEach()` it has as separate function context for each iteration so mine solves the problem that way.